# Non-blocking thread pool that posts results as soon as they're ready for the main thread to access

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool()

def calc(i):
    return i * 2

def done(results):
    for result in results:
        print(result)

def loop():
    pool.map_async(calc, [0, 1, 2, 3], callback = done):

while True:
    loop()
```

I'm using a thread pool setup as described in this simplified example. It works as expected: The main loop asks the pool to compute a set of results via `map_async` each time it runs, the pool uses the `calc` function to process the given items, when ready the `done` function is called with a list containing all results which in this case would always be `[0, 2, 4, 6]`.

What I want to achieve: I'd like the thread pool to run the callback function whenever any result has finished processing, or add it to a list the main thread can see and modify at any time. The pool stops calling the callback after the last result is calculated, until the main loop triggers it again and the process repeats.

The goal is for worker threads to post processed results as fast as they can, for the main thread to find as many results as possible whenever it executes even if they aren't all ready. Using `result.get()` isn't an option since fetching the result must not block the main thread, that's intended as an optional setting if you want to run in synced mode. I'm fine with either using a callback defined in the pool, or having each finished result added to an array as long as the main loop can see and processes finished items from it which are then discarded.

Worth noting that it's not mandatory for the main thread to give the array to the thread pool, `[0, 1, 2, 3]` is a constant variable in the class, but other variables the `calc` function works need to be updated from the main thread each call. An item is assigned to each thread still... for instance my array presumes there are 4 processes, each one is tasked with computing one of the numbers. I don't expect it to work exactly as I imagine but please let me know what comes closest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback fuction for `map_async` is only called when all results are ready.

If you want a callback function to be called as soon as a function returns, you can iteratively submit jobs to [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) instead:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep
from random import random

def calc(i):
    sleep(random())
    return i * 2

def done(result):
    print(result)

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    while True:
        for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
            pool.apply_async(calc, (i,), callback=done)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/StormyKnottyGeeklog

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work just as intended! Just a few questions: If I want an optional setting to make the main thread still wait for the pool to finish, how can I still add that in this setup? Also how do I get the program to quit... `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` no longer seems to be working.

Comment: Can you show an example? `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` is working as demoed: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/ScaredMiserlyFactors

Comment: I think it may be due to too much work being given to the threads that they have a hard time stopping, if so it's an issue in my code that I'll have to identify and resolve. One more question if I may: Do you think there's a way for the callback function to know the thread ID as a second parameter?

Comment: You're welcome. The callback function always takes only one parameter, so you can make the worker function return the thread ID along with the result as a tuple instead. Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/IrritatingImpoliteOutliers